# Landing Page Sign Up Flow

Tags: landing-page

I have a landing page I am sending users to: http://example.com/free30  This is the page I am directing new users to from one of my ads.

Now, I have a question (obviously):

On my landing pages, I need to collect user information, which includes credit card information. In sign up, a user can enter their email, password and name, or can sign up by way of Facebook. I also need to collect credit card information. If I go the FB route, I will have to redirect the user to another page to collect their credit card information. So my question:

Landing page: should I just do sign up (facebook / email, paswd, etc) then redirect to a credit card page or is there another pattern I should use? My goal is to get their credit card as quickly as possible.

Comment: Any reasons why they’ll surrender their CC information to a landing page linked from an Ad? Do they know / trust the company they are giving the info to? How far down the funnel are the users when looking at the landing page / registration / CC form?

Comment: I will be honest. I have never really done a proper landing page. What would be a good / traditional flow?

Comment: Asking for user registration and CC info after clicking an Ad link is in most cases not a good practice. Users usually get familiar with the company, the product first, check youtube videos, etc and then make the decision to purchase when convinced. This is how the funnel works. Apply it to real life, you wouldn’t give up your CC info to any stranger on the street selling a service or product you have never seen before. That’s the escenario the Ad > Landing Page > CC info flow is portraying.

Comment: However, it might be justifiable given your specific use case. That’s why I was asking for specifics. Who is using this, where are they seeing the ad, why would they buy the service / product upfront.

Comment: It's not a major life changing website, just online music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users lands on landing page, learns about your service, decides to register / subscribe and is taken to a registration / payment screen.

On registration, the user can either register through email or facebook. If facebook, you’ll have to show some sort of status message that confirms the website has received the data from Facebook. After receiving the validation, the email, password etc fields would become non-required.

[image]